# Huffman Tree with Max-Height, Nice Questions?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, compression, huffman-code

I ran into a nice question in one Solution of Homework in DS course.
which of the following (`for large n`) create the most height for `Huffman Tree`. the elements of each sequence in following option shows `the frequencies of character in input text` and not shown the characters.

```
1) sequence of n equal numbers

2) sequence of n consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

3) sequence <1,2,3,...,n>

4) sequence <1^2,2^2,3^2,...,n^2>
```

> Anyone could say, why this solution select (2)? thanks to anyone.

Comment: I think it's better to post this type of questions here: https://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyze the various options here.

A sequence of N equal numbers means a balanced tree will be created with the actual symbols at the bottom leaf nodes.

[image: same numbers]

A sequence 1-N has the property that as you start grouping the two lowest element their sum will quickly rise above other elements, here's an example:

[image: 1-N sequence]

As you can see, the groups from 4+5 and 7+8 did not by themselves contribute to the height of the tree.

After grouping the two 3-nodes into a 6, nodes 4 and 5 are the next in line, which means that each new group formed won't contribute to its height. Most will, but not all, and that's the important fact.

A sequence using squares (note: squares as in the third sequence in the question, `1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, ..., N^2`, not square diagram elements) has somewhat the same behavior as a sequence of 1-N, some of the time other elements than the one that was just formed will be used, which cuts down on the height:

[image: squares]

As you can see here, the same happened to 36+49, it did not contribute to the height of the tree.

However, the fibonacci sequence is different. As you group the two lowest nodes, their sum will at most topple the next item but not more than one of them, which means that each new group being formed will be used in the next as well, so that **each new group formed will contribute to the height of the tree**. This is different from the other 3 examples.

[image: fibonacci sequence]

Comment: Seems I was mistaken about the squares, let me ponder it.

Comment: A sequence using squares has the exact same behavior so I won't detail that here. !!!!?

Comment: Yes, squares, 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, etc. But my initial text was incorrect, corrected it now.